# Is 'low effort post' a valid close reason?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I noticed a post today with a close vote, with the reason being something along the lines of:

> This is a very low effort post which could be solved with the first
> google hit

I'm not doubting that's true, but is it a valid reason to close a post? Usually on SO downvotes are the way to respond to a low-effort post, not a close vote.

Answer (score 3):

I would say no unless google hits bioinfo.SE, then it is a duplicate, and in that case it should be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Closed votes are subject to a vote anyway on administration queue and I think (pretty certain) it is ultimately the mods decision whether to close.

The problem with 'first Google hit' as a reason is that Google's priority list is always changing. So if it is the top hit today, in a week or two it could disappear from the front page.

The other issue if we're looking up a basic e.g. coding, matter, cause you just forget, e.g. Python printing using `.format`, `%`, or `f"{}"` because `+` isn't cool then Googling stackexchange is quickest way to the solution rather than having to wade through beginners websites on how to code which can be 'not time efficient' is perhaps the politest way to say it.

To prove it ... Google

> .format python printing stackoverflow

Top Google hit (for now) is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517355/string-formatting-in-python) describing `.format`, `%` and `f""`. In fact I didn't know that `f"{}" were Python 3.6 onwards.

> .format python printing

Top hit is geekforgeeks.com where there is a lot more words and less information.

... and Googling site:bioinformatics.stackexchange.com (bit of a mouthful) should be something I do more.

Comment: If a post gets five close votes from the community, then it will be closed without moderator help. Moderators can re-open closed questions if they think there is merit in that.

Comment: Thanks @gringer thats good to know